# Postgres table partitioning based on table name

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, database-partitioning, postgresql-11

I have a table that stores information about weather for specific events and for specific timestamps. I do insert, update and select (more often than delete) on this table. All of my queries query on timestamp and event_id. Since this table is blowing up, I was considering doing table partitioning in postgres.

1. I could also think of having multiple tables and naming them "table_< event_id >_< timestamp >" to store specific timestamp information, instead of using postgres declarative/inheritance partitioning. But, I noticed that no one on the internet has done or written about any approach like this. Is there something I am missing?
2. I see that in postgres partitioning, the data is both kept in master as well as child tables. Why keep in both places? It seems less efficient to do inserts and updates to me.
3. Is there a generic limit on the number of tables when postgres will start to choke?

Thank you!

Comment: How big is "blowing up"?

Comment: I am planning for a phase 1, where I have to handle 1-2bil rows. And a phase 2 for 10-20bil rows. Can i do without partitioning at all for phase1?

Answer (score 0):

re 1) Don't do it. Why re-invent the wheel if the Postgres devs have already done it for you by providing declarative partitioning

re 2) You are mistaken. The data is **only** kept in the partition to which it belongs to. It just *looks* as if it is stored in the "master".

re 3) there is no built-in limit, but anything beyond a "few thousand" partitions is probably too much. It will still work, but especially query *planning* will be slower. And sometime the query execution might also suffer because runtime partition pruning is not as efficient any more.

Given your description you probably want to do hash partitioning on the event ID and then create range sub-partitions on the timestamp value (so each partition for an event is again partitioned on the range of the timestamps)

Comment: But, if my table name describes the partition, why shouldn't I directly query my partition instead of the master? That will reduce the query planning time, isn't it?

Comment: might reduce query planning time but most probably will increase seeking time, i.e. if table is not open, open the file, seek to it etc. when number of files reach thousands, just opening a file would take quite some time. so no, table names would only increase complexity for you

Comment: @DivyaKonda: then you need to change your SQL statement each time you run your query for a different event. If you use built-in partitioning (rather than implementing your own), you always use the same table name in your selects, you only pass different parameters and Postgres uses the best plan to retrieve the data. You can change the partitioning strategy without changing your code that dynamically generates the SQL query. Believe me: you do **not** want to do that.

Comment: @Aurangzeb isn't it the same process for opening a partition? So, the seek time would be the same in both cases, right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Understood. What if I use the declarative partitioning, but specify the partition table name while doing inserts or updates? Then the query planning time would be much better right? In the code, I can just have a function that generates the name of the table. So, if I change my partitions, all I need to do is change that function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what do you think of hash partitioning of the timestamps? Then I can specify the number of tables I want and keep it to that number? Not sure if that will cause any performance implications though.